# Jquery UI Autocomplete how to get source of ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I make an Google Request, alle fine. In my Streets variable I have an array of values. But autocomplete doesn´t show them.

Does andybody have an idea what´s wrong here?

```
 source:  function() {
        $.get(googleAPI + '"' + postCodeString + ' ' + cityString + ', ' + this.term + '"', function (response) {

            var Streets =[];

            $.map(response.results, function (item) {
                // Get address_components
                // console.log(item)
                for (var i = 0; i < item.address_components.length; i++) {
                    var addressType = item.address_components[i].types[0];

                    if (addressType === 'route') {
                       return Streets.push(item.address_components[i].long_name);
                    }
                }


            });
            return Streets;
            // console.log(Streets);

        });
```

Comment: Before you return `Streets`, can you run it to the console and provide an example of the value? Also `Streets is created within your $.get(), so it's out of scope to return. If you define it before, then it should work.

Comment: Its an array like ["name","name2"]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only checking the first element is the `types` array:

```
 item.address_components[i].types[0]
```

If the "route" type isn't in that position, it will never find it.

You need to iterate through all the elements of that array